# (JavaFX) How to show temporary popup (OSD) when action performed?

Tags: popup, tableview, javafx-8, alert

I am looking for a way to implement a simple, popup that shows on screen for only a few seconds; possibly similar to how many music programs will show the new artist/song information in the corner of the screen when a new song starts.

I want to be able to show a brief confirmation that a certain action has been performed successfully.  In my case, double-clicking on a `TableView` cell will copy the contents of the cell to the `Clipboard.`  However, I want to show some indication to the user that this has been done.

Will I need a customer `Alert` or manual `Tooltip` for this or is there an existing API that I haven't found yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use whatever popup-window implementation is the most convenient, and use a `PauseTransition` to hide it after the required time:

```
// can use an Alert, Dialog, or PopupWindow as needed...
Stage popup = new Stage();
// configure UI for popup etc...

// hide popup after 3 seconds:
PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(3));
delay.setOnFinished(e -> popup.hide());

popup.show();
delay.play();
```

Comment: Thank you, @James_D.  I ended up using `Timeline` instead, as `PauseTransition` wasn't working out.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to James_D answer i recommend:

> [Notifications](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/Notifications.html)

[image]

They are build in [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/) library and doing what you need.

Example:

```
Notifications.create()
              .title("Title Text")
              .text("Hello World 0!")
              .showWarning();
```